# For what $a\in \mathbb{R}$ does this limit exist?

Tags: limits

We have the limit $\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty} \bigg(\frac{(at-1)}{a^2t}+\frac{ce^{-at}}{t}\bigg)$ with $c\in\mathbb{R}$.

For what $a\in \mathbb{R}$ does this limit exist?

For example, I know that for $a=0$, it does not exist.

Comment: For $a>0$......Try to apply L'Hospital rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $a \neq 0$ you can write
$$\frac{at-1}{a^2t}+ c \frac{e^{-at}}{t} = \frac1a -\frac{1}{a^2t} + c \frac{e^{-at}}{t}$$
So for $t \to \infty$ the limit is $\frac1a$ if $a> 0$, $\pm \infty$ for $a < 0$ (it depends on the sign of $c$).

In particular, for $a \neq 0$, the limit exists.

Comment: But you agree that for a=0 it does not exist?

Comment: The expression is not even defined if $a=0.$

Comment: No. For $a=0$ the expression $\lim \dots$ does not make sense: technically the function does not exist. And now, if you have no function, then it does not make sense to say that "the limit does not exist". It's something like saying "Does it exist the limit $\lim_{t \to \infty} \emptyset$?"